# Fill in column in dataframe with the selected list value

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a lot of addresses in excel file. I have import it and store it in dataframe. Now I want to detect the states in each address and show it in new column. How do I loop for every row in my dataframe and add the value of the states in that row?

List of all states:

```
allstates=['SELANGOR','JOHOR','KELANTAN','MALACCA','NEGERI SEMBILAN','PAHANG','PENANG','PERAK','PERLIS',
          'SABAH','SARAWAK','TERENGGANU','KUALA LUMPUR','K. LUMPUR','LABUAN','PUTRAJAYA']
```

and below is how I want my dataframe to be:

```
Address                             |    States
-------------------------------------------------------
311 Jalan Springhill SELANGOR       |    *SELANGOR*
31 Jalan Segamat JOHOR              |    *JOHOR*
```

I want the states (example:SELANGOR) to insert in the states column

Comment: You should accept the answers if you think the answers are correct. You can choose multiple too

Comment: @YusufBaktir. User know that he should accept answers. It is not possible to choose multiple answers: it is possible to upvote all but just one can be choose.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try? You are showing not effort...

Comment: @David García Bodego. He was a new user. That's why. A lot of questions go unaccepted here in Stackoverflow.

Comment: @YusufBaktir, I know. He already accepted one.

Comment: @David García Bodego. Yes, I have seen that myself too.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego noted. thanks for your advice. I will improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['States'] = df.Address.str.extract('({})'.format('|'.join(allstates)))
```

If you are certain (or want) that the state names appear only at the end of the addresses:

```
df['Sates'] = df.Address.str.extract('({})$'.format('|'.join(allstates)))
```

Output:

```
                         Address     Sates
0  311 Jalan Springhill SELANGOR  SELANGOR
1         31 Jalan Segamat JOHOR     JOHOR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('states.csv')
print(data)
                         Address
0  311 Jalan Springhill SELANGOR
1         31 Jalan Segamat JOHOR

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    value = row.Address
    State = value.split()[-1:][0]
    data.loc[index,'State'] = State

print(data)
                         Address     State
0  311 Jalan Springhill SELANGOR  SELANGOR
1         31 Jalan Segamat JOHOR     JOHOR
```

Comment: sory. maybe u not understand my question. I have edit the question.